# AWS Gateway subroutes support for Asp.Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, routes, aws-api-gateway

I have created a simple AWS Serverless "Asp.Net Core minimal" application and everything works as expected because the application(lambda) is bound to the root route of the Api gateway.
Here is the configuration:

```json
      "Events": {
          "ProxyResource": {
            "Type": "Api",
            "Properties": {
              "Path": "/{proxy+}",
              "Method": "ANY"
            }
          },
          "RootResource": {
            "Type": "Api",
            "Properties": {
              "Path": "/",
              "Method": "ANY"
            }
          }
        }
```

But if to change the root route to some subroute, for example **"/hello"**,

```json
     "Events": {
          "ProxyResource": {
            "Type": "Api",
            "Properties": {
              "Path": "/hello/{proxy+}",
              "Method": "ANY"
            }
          },
          "RootResource": {
            "Type": "Api",
            "Properties": {
              "Path": "/hello/",
              "Method": "ANY"
            }
          }
        }
```

everything stops working and the application constantly returns a 404 error instead of a welcome message.

Here is the application code:

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddAWSLambdaHosting(LambdaEventSource.RestApi);
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

app.MapControllers();
app.MapGet("/", () => "Welcome to running ASP.NET Core Minimal API on AWS Lambda");

app.Run();
```

Is it possible somehow to explain for the application that now it is bound to the subroute?

Comment: `app.MapGet("/hello",...` maybe?

Comment: It's the first what I have tried and it works but removes flexibility to deploy a lambda to any URL without touching the code

Comment: You can’t have an application that uses controllers without checking the request object, map to dynamic routes.

Answer (score 0):

you need to change the url in function. It needs to be like:

```
app.MapGet("/hello", () => "Welcome to running ASP.NET Core Minimal API on AWS Lambda");
```

And if you have any route parameters you can also use

```
app.MapGet("/hello/{name}", (string name) => "Welcome to running ASP.NET Core Minimal API on AWS Lambda");
```